# how to delete a file when pdf size is 0byte in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can we delete or move a file when PDF size is 0Byte.

i have placed sample files and sample code.

Collapse | Copy Code

```
     If file.exist(d:\source\test1.pdf) then
          File.move(d:\source\test1.pdf, d:\destination\test1.pdf)
      End If
```

or

```
   If file.exist(d:\source\test1.pdf) then
      File.delete(d:\source\test1.pdf, d:\destination\test1.pdf)
    End If
```

both code doesn't work when pdf size is 0
Note: We cannot preview this pdf. we can Check after downloading pdf from below location

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_nzYHWVJJ7KaVZfQUZJVmsxUXM/view?usp=sharing[^]

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to delete a file I would recommend using the `System.IO` namespace... Make sure to import `System.IO` namespace at the top of your class...

```
System.IO.File.Delete(d:\source\test1.pdf)
```

You are also using `File.Delete` wrong... Not sure if you overlooked this or not?

```
  If file.exist(d:\source\test1.pdf) then
      File.Delete(d:\source\test1.pdf, d:\destination\test1.pdf) 'Only should be your file...
  End If
```

Please see this link... 
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/79699-undeletable-file-delete.html

Comment: even i have tried your solution, i couldn't delete the file. Any alternate solution for this.Plz note that, our pdf size is "0 BYTE"

Comment: @user2944173 please see link I have provided for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use
`My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("yourfile.pdf")`
or
`System.IO.File.Delete("yourfile.pdf")`
I've tried both of these methods with your 0 byte pdf file and they both are working perfectly fine.

Answer (score -2):

The [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class can be used to retrieve details about a file.

```
Dim myFile As New System.IO.FileInfo("myFile.txt")
Dim myFilesize As Long = myFile.Length
```

Then you can use [Mr CoDeXeR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354122/242584) to delete your file.

```
If (myFilesize = 0) Then
    System.IO.File.Delete("myFile.txt")
End If
```

Alternately, you could recycle the same FileInfo object:

```
If (myFilesize = 0) Then
    Try
        myFile.Delete
    Catch e As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
    End Try
End If
```

If you are receiving an `IOException` error, you may need to ensure that any streams you used to download the file are closed before trying to delete.

Comment: By using system.io.file.delete doesnt work.for 0 byte pdf. Plz note that, our pdf size is "0 BYTE"

Comment: We're you getting any errors previously, or did the delete fail silently? I've added an example with exception handling.

Comment: when iam moving Pdf file, It POPS Error as"THE PROCESS cannot access the file because it is being used by another system"

Comment: If it can't be moved because its locked, it can't be deleted either. Your problem is not that the suggested Delete methods don't work. It sounds like you have some file streams left open elsewhere in your code.